# Browser displays Arabic numbers on different order

Tags: html, reactjs, arabic, arabic-support

I'm having a small bug on my web. On About Us section of my website I want to pass a phone number to the contact information, also my web support different languages, but the problem is that when translating to Arabic language numbers display on a different order on the browser but on the vs code they display correctly also when pasting them to google translate they are translated on latin numbers correctly only the problem is that on the browser they are displayed on different order.

This is how they look on vs code
[image: Array of numbers]

And this is how they are displayed on the browser
[image: Numbers on the browser]

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: What to you exactely mean with "wrong order" that the letters are from "right to left" instead of "left to right"?

Comment: @TRIIX If you see closer the order on vs code is different from the order displayed on the browser I want the order of numbers to be displayed the same like they are on vs code

Comment: Alright, can you try and add this attribute to your tag: dir="rtl"

If that doesn't work could you please provide the code how you want to show the phone number :)

Comment: @TRIIX I tried it but it changes the order again but not the way I want I posted an answer (that is question) to clarify my question more if you have time to check it and give me an answer

Comment: I highly suspect that the error here is in VS Code, not the browser. Validate your source code with a hex editor (on unix, I use `xxd`, on Windows you can use `Format-Hex` in PowerShell). I expect that the digits are not in the order you think they are in the source.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making the question more clear and short 
This is a number writed on **Latin** on vs-code
[image: number photo]

Now this is the same number writed on **Arabic** numbers
[image: Arabic number image]

And I want that the **Arabic number** should display on **browser** Like it is on the **vs code** but the browser displays the **Arabic numbers** on different order
[image: Browser numbers image]

Even if I try `dir="rtl"` It also changes the order but not as I want

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The display order of the clusters of digits depend on the inherited direction. In VS Code, your directionality is LTR, while in your web page the inherited directionality will be RTL, so order of subsets of digits will change. It may be sufficient to add `dir=ltr` to the element, although you might need to also add the `bdi` element with a `dir=ltr`.